# QQmlApplicationEngine list index out of range issue

Tags: qt, qml, pyside

I am trying to run the last 2 examples from this [website](https://www.programmersought.com/article/32025290109/) and end up with
`root = engine.rootObjects()[0]  # type: QObject IndexError: list index out of range` error for both examples (Signal connection for root layout) (Signal connection of other qml file)

If it helps, I put all the example files onto the same directory level and changed the import statements to Pyside6 (from PySide6.QtCore...) instead of PySide2. I also added my version of the code if it makes it easier to see:

main.py:

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication


def say(s):
    print(s)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile('main.qml'))
    # Get the root object.
    root = engine.rootObjects()[0]  # type: QObject
    # Find the target object. Since our target object is Window, which is the root object. So use it directly.
    target_view = root
    # Bind signal.
    target_view.say.connect(say)  # The former one is the signal of qml, and the latter one is from Python
    # say() method.
    
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 600; height: 400

    signal say(string s)

    Button {
        text: "hello"
        onClicked: say(text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually that means that there's an issue with your QML code, and those are usually printed out. Do you see any errors in the output? In any case, you should check that rootObjects() doesn't return an empty list before accessing it. In C++ a common way to handle errors is connect to the objectCreated signal of the engine and exit the app if the object is null. Not sure what the equivalent is in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible causes of the error are:

- The path of the .qml is incorrect so the .qml is not loaded.
- The loading of the .qml is not synchronous as you are assuming.
- The .qml has some error (syntax for example)

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QUrl
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


def say(s):
    print(s)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "main.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)
        else:
            root = engine.rootObjects()[0]
            target_view = root
            target_view.say.connect(say)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(handle_object_created, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    engine.load(url)

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

But anyway I don't prefer to use rootObjects but instead export a QObject:

```py
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QObject, Qt, QUrl, Signal
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


class Helper(QObject):
    say = Signal(str)


def say(s):
    print(s)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    helper = Helper()
    helper.say.connect(say)

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("helper", helper)

    filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "main.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(handle_object_created, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    engine.load(url)

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 400

    Button {
        text: "hello"
        onClicked: helper.say(text)
    }

}
```